# Can you use mock_open to simulate serial connections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, pyserial

Morning folks,

I'm trying to get a few unit tests going in Python to confirm my code is working, but I'm having a real hard time getting a Mock anything to fit into my test cases.  I'm new to Python unit testing, so this has been a trying week thus far.

The summary of the program is I'm attempting to do serial control of a commercial monitor I got my hands on and I thought I'd use it as a chance to finally use Python for something rather than just falling back on one of the other languages I know.  I've got pyserial going, but before I start shoving a ton of commands out to the TV I'd like to learn the unittest part so I can write for my expected outputs and inputs.

I've tried using a library called dummyserial, but it didn't seem to be recognising the output I was sending.  I thought I'd give mock_open a try as I've seen it works like a standard IO as well, but it just isn't picking up on the calls either.  Samples of the code involved:

```
def testSendCmd(self):
    powerCheck = '{0}{1:>4}\r'.format(SharpCodes['POWER'], SharpCodes['CHECK']).encode('utf-8')
    read_text = 'Stuff\r'
    mo = mock_open(read_data=read_text)
    mo.in_waiting = len(read_text)
    with patch('__main__.open', mo):
        with open('./serial', 'a+b') as com:
            tv = SharpTV(com=com, TVID=999, tvInput = 'DVI')
            tv.sendCmd(SharpCodes['POWER'], SharpCodes['CHECK'])
            com.write(b'some junk')
    print(mo.mock_calls)
    mo().write.assert_called_with('{0}{1:>4}\r'.format(SharpCodes['POWER'], SharpCodes['CHECK']).encode('utf-8'))
```

And in the SharpTV class, the function in question:

```
def sendCmd(self, type, msg):
    sent = self.com.write('{0}{1:>4}\r'.format(type,msg).encode('utf-8'))
    print('{0}{1:>4}\r'.format(type,msg).encode('utf-8'))
```

Obviously, I'm attempting to control a Sharp TV.  I know the commands are correct, that isn't the issue.  The issue is just the testing.  According to documentation on the mock_open page, calling `mo.mock_calls` should return some data that a call was made, but I'm getting just an empty set of []'s even in spite of the blatantly wrong `com.write(b'some junk')`, and `mo().write.assert_called_with(...)` is returning with an assert error because it isn't detecting the write from within sendCmd.  What's really bothering me is I can do the examples from the mock_open section in interactive mode and it works as expected.

I'm missing something, I just don't know what.  I'd like help getting either dummyserial working, or mock_open.

Comment: What's the type of `self.com`? Whatever type that is, that's the type you need to patch out.

Comment: It's technically a serial.Serial() instance (pyserial), but besides in_waiting there's not a lot of difference between a read() on pyserial and a read() on a standard open().  At least not how I'm using it.  Changing out the patch, I've got mostly the same code except the following changes:

    `mo = mock_opening(read_data=read_text)`
    `with patch('serial.Serial', mo):`
        `with serial.Serial() as com:`
            `tv = SharpTV(com=com...)`

Comment: The problem is that you're patching out the builtin `open`, which may or may not be what you need to be mocking. Why not just patch the `com` object and be done with it? Furthermore, that function is so simple that it hardly warrants a test...especially if you're going to mock out the write operation...

Comment: Digging into dummyserial I found that it's decoding my input back into a string and checking against my dictionary for an actual string versus a byte encoded string.  I've adjusted that and it seems like it's working for me now.  I have more tests to do beyond this simple sendCmd, but I wanted to make sure I could at least get _this_ working before moving onto (slightly) harder things like testing TV status codes loaded from a config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer one part of my question, I figured out the functionality of dummyserial.  The following works now:

```
def testSendCmd(self):
    powerCheck = '{0}{1:>4}\r'.format(SharpCodes['POWER'], SharpCodes['CHECK'])
    com = dummyserial.Serial(
            port='COM1',
            baudrate=9600,
            ds_responses={powerCheck : powerCheck}
            )
    tv = SharpTV(com=com, TVID=999, tvInput = 'DVI')
    tv.sendCmd(SharpCodes['POWER'], SharpCodes['CHECK'])
    self.assertEqual(tv.recv(), powerCheck)
```

Previously I was encoding the dictionary values as `utf-8`.  The dummyserial library decodes whatever you `write(...)` to it so it's a straight string vs. string comparison.  It also encodes whatever you're `read()`ing as latin1 on the way back out.